# How to make generic react components using Redux connect decorator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a project with many components like:

```
 @connect((store) => {
  return {
    metrics: store.billing_reports_metrics.billing_reports_metrics,
    startDateOnLoad: store.billing_reports_metrics.startDateAutohealing,
    endDateOnLoad: store.billing_reports_metrics.endDateAutohealing,
    metricsFetched: store.billing_reports_metrics.fetched,
    errorMsg: store.billing_reports_metrics.error,
    fetching: store.billing_reports_metrics.fetching
  };
})
class BillingReportsController extends MyComponent {
  constructor(props){
      let custom_methods = ['refreshTableOnDateChange', 'renderAllTables'];
      super(props, custom_methods);
      this.props.dispatch({type: "SET_BILLING_REPORTS_START_DATE", payload: moment().tz('US/Eastern').subtract(1, 'hours')})
      this.props.dispatch({type: "SET_BILLING_REPORTS_END_DATE", payload: moment().tz('US/Eastern')})
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchBillingReportsMetrics(this.props.startDateOnLoad,this.props.endDateOnLoad))
  }
```

I'd like to make this type of controller generic, which would be easy if it was a regular component you could pass props. Problem is the props get passed in through a decorator, and each of these components are in separate files

How can I make this generic and do the same thing for types of reports besides `billing_reports` across my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using custom [Higher-order Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html)

That way, you should be able to pass name of the state property of your liking to the decorator ('billing_reports' in example) or other props as needed.